# C# SqlCeDataReader getValue of date return different format on the same query

Tags: c#, sqlcedatareader

I have the following code

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM table";
SqlCeDataReader reader = ConectorSQLCE.consultar(rutaArchivo, sqlQuery);
String value = "";

try
{
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {

                    if (reader.GetValue(i) == DBNull.Value)
                        value += "*";
                    else
                    {
                        value += reader.GetValue(i).ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

When `reader.GetValue(i)` is a `datetime` field, sometimes it returns `01/01/2014 0:00:00` and other times returns `01/01/2014 12:00:00 a.m.`

Why does this happen? The string value is used then to a hash code, so I have for the same row different hashes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it would do that, but if the time field is always the same, why don't you just convert it to a `.ShortDateString()`, then you don't have to worry about inconsistencies. You can also convert it on the sql side if you call each column you need by name and use a `convert(varchar,dateField,101)`

Comment: The code is in an exe file and for the moment I cant rebuild it. So first I want to know why it could happend

Comment: Have you tried checking what is stored in the database? is it a DateTime field, or is it a type of varchar and it was just stored differently to begin with?

Comment: its a datetime field. The database is a compact edition